# как использовать ffmpeg на heroku

Tags: python, discord.py, heroku, ffmpeg

Я пишу discord бота на python и решил загрузить на heroku его для того, чтобы можно было начать использовать, но у меня возникает проблема: я не могу его там использовать, выводит ошибку `discord.errors.ClientException: ffmpeg.exe was not found` проблема заключается в том, что я загружал ffmpeg в buildpack, но он всё равно не работает
вот мой код:

```
@client.command()
async def play(ctx, arg):
    global vc

    try:
        voice_channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        vc = await voice_channel.connect()
    except:
        print('Уже подключен или не удалось подключиться')

    if vc.is_playing():
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention}, музыка уже проигрывается.')

    else:
        with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(arg, download=False)

        URL = info['formats'][0]['url']

        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg.exe", source=URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))

        while vc.is_playing():
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        if not vc.is_paused():
            await vc.disconnect()

@client.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
```

Comment: Там линукс, так что точно не exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите явное указание пути к исполняемому файлу.

```py
executable="ffmpeg.exe"
```

Если у вас и вправду загружен нужный `buildpack`, то путь к `ffmpeg` будет прописан в переменной среды и библиотека сама обнаружит его.

*Ну и как указал [Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy) на сервере с ядром линукса уж точно не будет работать файл с расширением `.exe` :)*